# Opening terminal window from python script using applescript and execute a script

Tags: python, terminal, applescript

I have a python script 'test.py' which takes arguments in batches of 50-100-150 etc.

Everytime I have to open multiple terminal windows (10-15 windows) and execute 'test.py' providing batches manually (which is exhaustive after some period of time)

I decided to write a separate script which can open terminal window recursively by providing arguments in batches.

The short script runs fine but throwing error if there's space in path to script file. I've tries numerous solutions provided on internet but none of them seems to work

Short code snippet:
from applescript import tell
yourCommand = 'python3 ~/Desktop/untitled folder/test.py <range of batch, Ex: 1 51>'
tell.app( 'Terminal', 'do script "' + yourCommand + '"')

What I've tried so far:

1. Enclosing folder with spaces in double quotes, Ex: "untitled folder"
2. Using "r", Ex: yourCommand = r'"python3 ~/Desktop/untitled folder/test.py <range of batch, Ex: 1 51>"'
3. Using backslashes, Ex: untitled\ folder
4. Using double backslashes, Ex: untitled\ folder

But everytime either the terminal window is not opening or if it is opening, it is throwing error "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users//Desktop/untitled': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Env: Mac OSX

Any help would be appreciated. I am sure I must be making some silly mistake, but not able to resolve it.

Screenshots:

script 1.py
[image: script 1.py]

output of 1.py
[image: output of 1.py]

Comment: Tried as you suggested but this is not opening TERMINAL window now

Comment: Hi @RobertKniazidis, I have 2 py scripts in 'untitled folder' i.e. 1.py and test.py, 1.py contains script which launches new terminal window and supposed to execute command stores in variable 'yourCommand'

1.py is executed from terminal window

I hope I am able to narrate the issue in a better manner now!!!

Answer (score 1):

when using **do shell script**:

```
do shell script "python3 ~/Desktop/untitled\\ folder/test.py"
```

when typing in the Terminal, or using **do script** command:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "python3 ~'/Desktop/untitled folder/test.py'"
end tell
```

The best practice is using **quoted form** to escape. Duplicating folder example in the Terminal:

```
set theSource to "/Desktop/TESTFiles/"
set theDestination to "/Desktop/TEST Files/"

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "ditto ~" & quoted form of theSource & " ~" & quoted form of theDestination
end tell
```

The same task in the **do shell script** along with the **quoted form** requires determining the home folder path before. That is, instead of the tilde:

```
set home to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
set theSource to quoted form of (home & "/Desktop/TESTFiles/")
set theDestination to quoted form of (home & "/Desktop/TEST Files/")

do shell script "ditto " & theSource & " " & theDestination
```

Comment: You need the second form, because you use **do script** as I see.

Comment: New terminal window is opening now with full path to 'test.py' file, but strangely it is showing error "can't open file '~/Desktop/untitled folder/test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". What I think is the error due to missing backslash after "untitled". Please suggest

Comment: I can't understand: do you still have file **test.ru** or **tets.ru**? Also, are there any extra spaces in the **untitled folder** name. I recommend that you more carefully check that the Posix path you specify is correct. Run **return Posix path of (choose file)** to check.

Comment: Also, pay special attention to the fact that the **tilde** character itself must remain outside the quotes.

Comment: Both the above observations are double checked and it was not the issue. File name was typo in original question and it is corrected as well to test.py, complete script which I am running is as below which is saved in file 1.py
**from applescript import tell
tell.app( 'Terminal', 'do script "' + "python3 ~'/Desktop/untitled folder/test.py'" + '"')**

Please also consider my suggestion in previous comment **What I think is the error due to missing backslash after "untitled"**

Comment: Screenshots are added in original post above.

Comment: Paste here what you get in result when executing **Posix path of (choose file)**, if you don't understand.

Comment: I ran **python3 ~'/Desktop/untitled folder/test.py'** in the Terminal were test.ru is python file which prints triangles. It worked fine. I got the error shown on your screenshots only when provided not correct posix path. So, I say again: run return Posix path of (choose file), copy the part of posix path of result you need, paste into single quotes of shell command, to avoid any strange issues with not correct provided posix path!!! – 
Robert Kniazidis
 7 mins ago     Delete

Comment: I added temporarly the second, demonstrative answer.

Comment: **I believe I've resolved the issue, by using absolute path starting from root / and enclosing the complete path in ' '**, but the same is not working when using tilde sign ~, can u plz suggest why it is not working with tilde sign?

Comment: All the tilde scripts I provided in the answers work for me on Catalina and have been tested several times. Therefore, it is difficult for me to explain why you have a problem with the tilde.

Answer (score 1):

Save following python script as **print trianlges.py** file in **untitled folder** folder of desktop.

```
max_size = 10

print(
    "(a)" + " " * (max_size) +
    "(b)" + " " * (max_size) +
    "(c)" + " " * (max_size) +
    "(d)" + " " * (max_size)
    )

for i in range(1, max_size + 1):

    print("*" * i, end = " " * (max_size - i + 3))

    print("*" * (max_size - i + 1), end = " " * (i - 1 + 3))

    print(" " * (i - 1) + "*" * (max_size - i + 1), end = " " * 3)

    print(" " * (max_size - i) + "*" * i)
```

Now, run following command in the Terminal to print triangles. As you can see, the path has spaces in the folder name and in the file name, and works fine:

**python3 ~'/Desktop/untitled folder/print triangles.py'**

Comment: Saved the above file with file name **print triangles.py** in folder **untitles folder** and using terminal executed command **python3 ~'/Desktop/untitled folder/print triangles.py'**, Regret to say but same error occurs in my Terminal window **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '~/Desktop/untitled folder/print triangles.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

Comment: **I believe I've resolved the issue, by using absolute path starting from root / and enclosing the complete path in ' '**, but the same is not working when using tilde sign **~**, can u plz suggest why it is not working with tilde sign?